AWS lamda-Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
My apache flink based project giving the error, mine is maven project and below the pom,can i exclude some of the dependencies to reduce the size of the jar, the error started coming after i tried to upgrade the flink to 1.19.0, with older version the size is not an issue. Also i am not sure if can exclude some of the not required dependecies of the flink because i don't have a test environment.
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myproj.user</groupId>
    <version>0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <kda.version>2.0.0</kda.version>
    <kda.runtime.version>1.2.0</kda.runtime.version>
    <flink.version>1.19.0</flink.version>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.903</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${kda.runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-hadoop-fs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-flink</artifactId>
        <version>${kda.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-logs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproj.drv</groupId>
        <artifactId>drv-zts-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.32</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcutil-jdk15on</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.72</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For log4j support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End For log4j support -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-json-protocol</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>protocol-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproj.user.lafaspot_common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common.core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    --add-reads jdk.attach=ALL-UNNAMED
                    -Dfile.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968 -Djava.library.path= -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
                    --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens java.base/java.util.jar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/javax.net.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/javax.net=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.72</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.79</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>METHOD</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.91</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.58</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.96</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                        <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                                        <maximum>3</maximum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>

